# CLI Utillity to search your gmail account

Tags: email

Is there a CLI utility to search your gmail account?  Perhaps by opening your default browser to gmail.com and placing implementing your search?

Comment: Gmail -> [OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org/) -> [notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/)...

Comment: Similar to @jasonwryan suggestion: 1) download email via IMAP, 2) grep through email, 3) profit!

Comment: But is there a way to do this online without having to download e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

[Imap-CLI](http://pythonhosted.org/Imap-CLI/REPL.html) should do the trick.  It's unclear if it supports Google's IMAP extensions ([X-GW-RAW](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions)), though.